# Passing property with enum to function expecting property with string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

can somebody explain me, why flow does not accept argument of more restrictive type to function expecting less restrictive type when it's an object property?

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCSAdjgK4ZgC8YA3qmGNvgFxgDOGATgJbEDmAGlQBfANzpmBAPIVylGvUZS2AcgByAQwBuq4SPQBjOMU5gocONTAAKAJRtZGedQB8tpU1x41W3frsJVGNTSgAjTS5rGz55NhJ5Ozc6BjAQ9jgYPAA6eH4bVViKPTAijECwUXQIrhsLOHtAoA

```
/* @flow */

type Input = {
  type: string,
};

type Output = {
  type: 'Nav',
}

const foo = (): Output => ({
  type: 'Nav',
});

const bar = (input: Input) => {
  console.log('input', input); 
}

bar(foo());
```

Error:

```
19: bar(foo());
        ^ Cannot call `bar` with `foo()` bound to `input` because string literal `Nav` [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `type`.
References:
8:   type: 'Nav',
           ^ [1]
4:   type: string,
           ^ [2]
```

Did I miss something in documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [variance](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/) should get you started on understand why more specific inputs are troublesome. In your case, Flow does not know what your function will do with the input, so there is concern that `bar` could modify its input. For example, `bar` may change `input.type` to `'some string'`, which would violate the `Output` type. You could mark `input` as a `$ReadOnly<Input>` type to provide Flow with a guarantee that `bar` will not modify `input`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I've read that, but totally forgot about this.